# on-screen calculation with DA

Tags: oracle-apex

when

```
:p1_radio_button_1 
:p1_radio_button_2 
:p1_radio_button_3
```

change,
dynamic actions fired to set values on

```
:p1_score_1
:p1_score_2
:p1_score_3
```

with simple math such as (:p1_lov_1's return value) * (a constant from global page) /100

and these changes on :p1_score_x fires another DA to do some other simple calculations.

eventually I am expecting a weighted_score to be calculated.

**

mechanically, it works. but when I click radio buttons a couple of times one after another, calculation goes crazy.

I believe my approach is wrong. What would you suggest? Should I submit the page after each radio button clicks?

Thanks in advance.

- APEX version 18.x
- browser Firefox
- OS windows

Answer (score 0):

I think chained dynamic actions are not the best idea. I changed the behaviour a little:

- placed a dummyButton
- hide realButton on page load
- redirected dummyButton to page inline dialog saying to end user "please click calcButton"
- show realButton when calcButton clicked
- hide dummyButton when calcButton clicked
- hide realButton & show dummyButton if anything changes on radioButtons

I wasn't sure if I should delete the post or reply it. admins; please delete if it somehow against the community rules.

thank you very much

Comment: You could "close" your question.